# React semantic UI table show and hide columns

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In version 1.2.1 of semantic UI React table, I can't find any native behaviour for showing or hiding columns in the :
https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#types-pagination

And actually, I'm not using columns, just rows, as in the first example:

```
<Table celled>
    <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Header>

    <Table.Body>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>
          <Label ribbon>First</Label>
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Body>
</Table>
```

Do I just need to use the standard hmtl css display none? I would have thought there would be some properties built into the table?

Comment: In react you can do it using the state management.

Example: 
1. In constructor, create this.state={hide:true}


in table if you want to hide a Table Row,

write like this:
{

(this.state.hide==false)?null:<Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Body>

}

It will not show that row.
This is because the react rendering is state based.

If you want to hide then you have to set the state as hide=true i.e.

this.setState({hide:true})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react you can do it using the state management.

Example:

1. In constructor, create

   this.state={hide:true}

in table if you want to hide a Table Row,

write like this:

```
{
(this.state.hide==false)?null:<Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Body>
}
```

It will not show that row.
This is because the react rendering is state based.

If you want to hide then you have to set the state as hide=true i.e.

```
this.setState({hide:true})
```

Comment: thanks Aijaz, could you point me to where in the docs I can find this? https://react.semantic-ui.com/

Comment: if you can share the code, I will do it for you because this is logical way.
i.e. as you disable button on api call and show loader, and when the response is returned you hide the loader, this also works similarly.